# Can't pan map far enough south

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

For some reason I can't pan the in-game map far enough south-east (past `Riften`). Basically I point my mouse at the bottom right of the screen and the map barely scrolls to Riften, it just wont go further.

I don't know how long it's been present but have only noticed it since I got the Dawnguard expansion (where I frequently try to fast travel to Fort Dawnguard). So it might be an issue in the base game too.

I can't find anyone else online mentioning it but I'd like to know if you guys know a fix. What I've been doing thus far is just fast travelling to a closer town, then immediately fast travelling from there (I am yet to experience the problem happening twice in a row).

It isn't a distance thing because I've traveled from the Fort to Castle Volkihar, it seems to be random, and only affects that south east corner of the map.

Comment: Did you try rotating the camera?

Comment: I've never rotated it, but I did try zooming (to no avail), also, simply exiting the map and entering again obviously doesn't work (that'd be a good enough fix right there! :P)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Default, the Skyrim map can be a little touchy when it comes to fast-traveling to the new Dawnguard locations.

The only reliable solution I've found is to rotate the map (by right-click dragging), which changes the angle and pushes the locations "up", making them much easier to select.

Comment: Agreed, rotating is the only way I've been able to reach Fort Dawnguard on the map.

Comment: So you've experienced it too? Or is this a general solution that should work? I'll try it as soon as it happens again, thanks

Comment: I've run into it. i didn't even know it was *possible* to rotate the map until i tried playing dawnguard!

Comment: @RavenDreamer same here - I'd never tried it before

Comment: I'm pretty sure when you're up top left it automatically rotates the map, and that's why rotating it back works. I think this because if I go from Solitude and pan over to Winterhold all the icons are smooshed together in a way that is only corrected by rotating back

Answer (score 1):

The way I've usually gotten the map to cooperate has been to Fast Travel in two hops; the map seems more willing to pan to the extreme edges if you're closer to them, so I find it easier to get it to pan over the Dawnguard Fort if I'm in or near Riften, and likewise easier to get to the areas that the Dawnguard DLC added in the North-west by if I'm in or near Solitude.

Comment: That's what I've been doing at the moment (I wrote it in the question), I was hoping for a "what causes it is X", "you can stop it by Y" or "you can mitigate it by Z", where Z doesn't take two loading screens :P thanks though

Comment: @Hashbrown Yeah, it seems to mostly be some limit of how far in total you can pan. Probably just an oversight that never really came up in the initial game, and so never really got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The "map" is actually an extreme camera pan of a very-highly LOD'd gameworld.  Like any other camera in the game, you can tweak the INI to change the view.

[Improved 3D World Map](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/2459) on the Skyrim Nexus is actually a collection of INI tweaks that improves the functionality of the map greatly, including letting you see the southernmost settlements, with a DIY guide as its primary download.